# CGI programming in D

Tags: cgi, d

I am interested learning more about the D programming programming language, and especially using it for CGI programs. I have had a look at the standard libraries (Phobos) and did not see any support for CGI. Does anyone know of any good examples of CGI programs written in D?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Adam Ruppe's library is probably the most complete CGI D solution at the moment:

https://github.com/adamdruppe/misc-stuff-including-D-programming-language-web-stuff

Answer (score 1):

Here is a cgi library for D I have written as a support library for a larger project.    MIT licensed, free to use however you want.

https://github.com/josephRice/cgi_d

Comment: Please provide links in comments, keep the answers for detailed answers. Eg: provide code example of the way your library is used.

Comment: Fabien - Usage of the library is in the project's README.md file.  Please see the link in my previous comment.   Thanks.

Comment: It is better to provide an example so it avoids people to open more links to get their answer. This is in Stackoverflow's guidelines for answers, please refer to them.

Comment: Fabien - It's a link to github project which is a library.  The comment provides an answer to the Parent question.    If people are interested in using the library that is where they go to learn about and download the library.  Also my comment is no different than Vladimir Panteleev comment pointing to Adam Ruppe's library.     Also Guideline  by definition - a general rule, principle, or piece of advice.   It is not a law, and they do not necessarily need to be followed.    in which, stating this again; my comment answers the posed question.   Thanks.